# Javascript - alert("zoo">"house") returns true

Tags: javascript

`alert("zoo">"house")` returns `true`.
Could anyone explain me why?

Comment: Sounds like you'd expected something else, what is it?

Comment: Everybody knows a zoo is greater than an ordinary house.

Comment: Really))) Even Javascript

Comment: On a sidenote, `alert("poo">"piss")` is also `true`, strange ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it does a lexical comparison, and `z` is greater than `h` (that is, the *code unit* for `z` has a higher numeric value than the code unit for `h`). If both strings started with the same character, the second character would be checked, and so on. Full details in turgid detail [in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5).

Answer (score 2):

strings are compared lexicographically.

[Wiki - Lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)