# Why does JavaScript consider "," to be smaller than "."?

Tags: javascript

`alert("," < ".")` returns `true` in JavaScript.

So why "," is smaller than "."?

Comment: Can you explain why it shouldn't be?

Comment: What is the part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23030037/1169519) you don't understand?

Comment: You are posting a lot of duplicates over the last couple of days... even near-duplicates of your _own_ questions, now. Please search and do some research before posting. I also ask you to stop writing "TAGS - " at the front of your question titles; Stack Overflow is not a forum. It has its own tagging mechanism which is superior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As from [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison%5fOperators) because:

> Strings are compared based on standard lexicographical ordering, using
>   Unicode values.

Which internally means `( ord(',') < ord('.') ) == ( 44 < 46 )`.

Comment: lots of +1 because everybody else is saying ASCII

Answer (score 3):

Because of the Unicode :

```
",".charCodeAt(0);
# output: 44
".".charCodeAt(0);
# output: 46
```

Comment: JavaScript uses Unicode, not ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses Unicode. Unicode of "," = 44 & Unicode of "." = 46 
therefore alert("," < ".") will always return true